# KMeans in pipeline with GridSearchCV scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, pipeline

I want to perform clustering on my text data. To find best text preprocessing parameters I made pipeline and put it in GridSearchCV:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect1', CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word"),
                   ('myfun', MyLemmanization(lemmatize=True,
                                           leave_other_words = True)),
                   ('vect2', CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",
                                          max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                          max_features=2000)),
                   ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                   ('clust',   KMeans(n_clusters=10, init='k-means++',
                                      max_iter=100, n_init=1, verbose=1))])
parameters = {'myfun__lemmatize': (True, False),
              'myfun__leave_other_words': (True, False)}
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters, n_jobs=1, scoring=score)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(text_data)
```

where `score`

```
score = make_scorer(my_f1, greater_is_better=True)
```

and `my_f1` is of form:

```
def my_f1(labels_true, labels_pred):
    # fancy stuff goes here
```

and is [specially](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html) designed for clustering

So my questions is: how to make that work? How to pass `labels_pred`, when as a kmeans nature I can only do

```
gs_clf.fit(data)
```

while in classification there is possible:

```
gs_clf.fit(data, labels_true)
```

I know I can write my custom function, like I did with `MyLemmanization`:

```
class MyLemmanization(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self,  lemmatize=True, leave_other_words=True):
        #some code here
    
    def do_something_to(self, X):
        # some code here
        return articles

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.do_something_to(X)  # where the actual feature extraction happens

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self  # generally does nothing
```

But how and what has to be done to KMeans or other clustering algorithm?

Comment: KMeans is not a classifier. It is unsupervised, so you can't just use supervised logic with it. You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist: one does not use KMeans to post existing labels. Use a supervised classifier if you have labels.

Comment: Yes, I know that I do classification here while using clustering method. The reason is, that I do research on preprocessing parameters. I use clustering, because unlike classification, it is more flexible and can find previously unknown topics. And the only way to see which parameter is better, is to evaluate by known labels. As I mentioned in the question, there is specially modified f1 score for this.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Lukas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom K-means where you use the labeled data to build the initial centroids and then let K-means do its magic.

You might also want to try [k-NN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#neighbors), even though it's a different method.

More importantly, you have a conceptual problem. You say one of the reasons you use clustering is because it might find previously unknown topics, but you also say you want to evaluate performance by comparing with known labels. You can't really have both, though...